# Non-Generic Contravariance

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, covariance

Say I have these two interfaces

```
public interface A
{

}

public interface B
{
   A a {get;}
}
```

And these two concrete Types

```
public class ConcreteA : A
{
}

public class ConcreteB : B
{
   public ConcreteA a {get;}
}
```

This does not compile because Interface B is expecting an interface A instead of a ConcreteA.

Currently I'm auto generating code with interfaces, and I ran into this senario.  Instead of Modifying all of my models to implement and Explicit interface definition in which would return the interface version of my concrete class, I would like to do this using some version of covariance, but I'm not sure if there is a way to do this or if this is a limitation of C#.

1. Is there an interface way version of contravariance that would allow me to do this?

   1.1 If there isn't is there an explicit reason why this isn't implement, or is there a senario in which would be problematic if this was implement?

Comment: You need generics because `B b = new ConcreteB();` would  allow you to set `a` to anything that implements `A`, not just `ConcreteA`.

Comment: @juharr your right thanks, I over looked that. Supposing you only had get the interface would still be able to be done but that would be a specific niche use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to make it generic for this to work

```
public interface B<T> where T : A
{
   T a {get; set;}
}

public class ConcreteA : A
{
}

public class ConcreteB : B<ConcreateA>
{
   public ConcreteA a {get; set;}
}
```

That's because

```
B b = new ConcreteB();
b.a = AnythingThatImplementsA;
```

would not be able to force you to only set it to something that is `ConcreteA` otherwise.

Comment: Your right I will accept this as an answer when the time limit allows me to